# Modal popup parameter transfer

Tags: javascript, html

http://www.quizboard-cheat.com/champions/rquotes.html?catid=17&number_items=999&sort_order=0&sort_column=0&show_quote=1&show_author=1&show_createdate=0&show_notes=0&quotation_marks=0

On that page, I have a ! within a picture, that does a modal popup, I have an onClick function on the button, but the event it not fired at all.

I have 4 parameters that I want to transfer to the modal popup, but what is wrong with the code as it is?

Comment: I know you posted a link to the site but its too much to go through all the code just to find the part you are working with. Can you post the jQuery/JS you are working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is not executing because the relevant HTML is not parsing correctly. The parsing fails because the same character (namely, `"`) is being used to delimit both attribute values and string-type arguments in the function.  Mixing single and double quotes is common practice.

Specifically, try changing

```
<button class="modalInput" onclick="params(17,3,"question","ice hockey");">...</button>
```

to

```
<button class="modalInput" onclick="params(17,3,'question','ice hockey');">...</button>
```